# NoMethodError in Coworking_spaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

i'm having this error:

undefined method `map_text_url' for #

This is my /Users/felipevelasquez/Desktop/APPS/meetrico/meetrico-production/app/views/coworking_spaces/_form.html.haml

```
23:   .field.columns
24:     = f.label :map_text_url, "Url Imagen del mapa"
25:     %br/
26:     = f.text_area :map_text_url, :size => "40x4", class: 'image-text'
27:   .field.columns
28:     = f.label :map_file, "O sube una imagen"
29:     - if @coworking_space.map_file?
```

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/coworking_spaces/new.html.haml

This is my new.html.haml

```
%h1 Nuevo Espacio
= render 'form'
= link_to 'Back', coworking_spaces_path
```

Where is the error?

Comment: You're using `f.` for the fields but I don't see a `form_for`? see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html 
you don't define the `f` in your code.

Comment: Is `undefined method `map_text_url' for #` really all you get? I'd expect it to say what the receiver was right after the `#`. Also, please show the stacktrace.

Comment: Hello Rafael, i`m new with ruby, could you explain me how to look for the stacktrace? Thanks Tijmenh i saw the link of FormHelper, but i have this code running in my server propertly in http://meetrico.com i supose if its running there is no problem with te form, i think this is with my db.

Comment: Hi guys! i solved it! It was an error in the migrations in database, thats fixed now. Thanks for helping!